# Can I identify element having an attribute_name containing a hyphen

Tags: ruby, watir, page-object-gem

## HTML code:

```html
<div class="Dashboard_Widget_Toolbar_Item disabled" data-widgetclientimplementation="Widget_Favorites">
  <img class="Dashboard_Widget_Toolbar_ItemImg" src="/WebCommon/Images/16x16_star.png">
  <div class="Dashboard_Widget_Toolbar_ItemName">Favorites</div>
  <div class="Dashboard_Widget_Toolbar_ItemDescrip">Shows items you have pinned from various applications</div>
</div>
```

## Question

(knowing that I am using the Page-Object gem)
Is it possible to identify a element by an attribute_name that contains a hyphen?
In my example, ideally I wanted to identify an element as:

```
self.div(:favorites_toolbar_item, data-widgetclientimplementation: "Widget_Favorites")
```

From browsing I believe the answer might rely on css selector? but I could not find any relevant info to try.

Thanks
JFF

Comment: `self.div(:favorites_toolbar_item, :"data-widgetclientimplementation": "Widget_Favorites")`

Comment: Getting an error with you solution    rb:37: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
.mentation": "Widget_Favorites")
.                               ^

Comment: This worked:   self.div(:favorites_toolbar_item, "data-widgetclientimplementation": "Widget_Favorites")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watir (and Page-Object) have support for data-* and aria-* attributes. You simply need to replace the dashes with underscores in the locator:

```
self.div(:favorites_toolbar_item, data_widgetclientimplementation: "Widget_Favorites")
```